# Adding a new Domain Controller to existing Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows, windows-server-2000

I have a Windows 2000 server and I want to add a Windows 2008 Server server to the forest.

Do I add the Windows 2008 server to the domain before running `DCPromo` or do I leave it off the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter. Since it saves time to DCPromo directly, do that.

MINOR CAVEAT: The SID of the Server 2008 install should be different than any of the existing machines. If you didn't clone this from another install (as in a virtualized environment), then you should be fine.

Comment: If I answered your question, please click the green checkmark next to the answer to indicate that the problem is resolved. Welcome to ServerFault!

Comment: Can't yet, you were too quick ;-). I will once I can

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to follow up if joining the DC doesn't work

Comment: Just an afterthought - doesn't the domain/forest need adprep'ing prior to adding a 2008 DC to a 2003 domain?

Comment: Yes. It does. Forestprep and Domainprep will both need to be ran against the 2003 server.

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown - even better, it's Windows 2000 :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll put this in as an answer since it is fairly important.

You'll need to [prepare](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753437%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) the forest using adprep before adding the new DC.